# Does AfterReturningAdvice start after of before Transaction closed?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I am using BeanPostProcessor which is executing some code after my `Service` methods are done.
But my `Service` is `@Transactional` also.

Is this "trigger" executes after of before end of Transaction in those methods?

```
@Component
public class MethodBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (findAnnotation(bean.getClass(), Service.class) != null) {
            var factory = new ProxyFactory(bean);
            factory.setProxyTargetClass(true);
            factory.addAdvice((AfterReturningAdvice) (returnValue, method, args, target) -> {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Refreshable.class)) {
                    var refreshableDto = (RefreshableDto) returnValue;
                    if (refreshableDto != null) {
                        refreshableDto.copyId();
                    }
                }
            });
            factory.setExposeProxy(true);
            return factory.getProxy();
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

It is working fine so I could assume it works exactly after transaction but I am not sure.
Is there are any place in docummentation or something where I can find that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the transaction in Spring is also implemented as an aspect and the transaction advice has a defined default order `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`. As the JavaDoc of [`Ordered`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) says the lowest order value comes first:

> The actual [order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html#getOrder--) can be interpreted as prioritization, with the first object (with the lowest order value) having the highest priority.

The order might be a bit confusing as `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE` that represents the highest precedence.

The information about the defined default order can be found in figure *Table 2. Annotation-driven transaction settings* of chapter [1.4.6. Using @Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) (reference documentation of the `5.3.x` version, other versions chaptering might differ, but the principle is the same).

You can change the order of the transactional AOP advice with two ways:

- Annotation driven configuration: `@EnableTransactionManagement(order = 123)`
- XML driven configuration: `<tx:annotation-driven order="123"/>`

The same your individual aspects defined with `@Aspect` beans can be further configured with `@Order` annotation.